# Embedded media manager for Azure Storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to find a solution where I can allow users to upload media to a container within Azure storage and also browse that container within a web application (ASP.NET MVC 4). I have found http://www.moxiemanager.com but the documentation and examples are quite sparse. I want to be able to select the container based on the username of the current user so this would need to be dynamic. Has anyone tried something something similar or is this not currently possible? I would ideally like to use some sort of javascript plugin to achieve this instead of having to create a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no ready to use solution available.

You can use Azure REST Api's to manage blob / containers or use .NET SDK.

There is Azure Storage Explorer that allows you to browse and manage content stored in it. As it is open source, you can download and learn how it works.

http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

As Thiago mentioned, there's no ready made solution available for this so you would need to write an application yourself. However I would not recommend using Azure Storage Explorer as it would require you to share your storage credentials with your team and thus giving them full access to your storage account.

One thing you may want to look into is Shared Access Signature functionality in Windows Azure Storage. This functionality allows you to grant time-bound granular access to various resources in your storage. For example, you could create a SAS URL for "container-a" in your storage account with write permission and a user with that SAS URL and an application which consumes this SAS URL to upload data in that container only. I realize that it's not exactly a 100% fit for the thing you're looking for but that could be a start.

Also today Windows Azure Storage announced support for CORS which would allow you to write pure HTML client based applications to interact with storage. You can read that blog post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more.aspx.

I wrote a few blog posts on Shared Access Signature and consuming them in HTML applications which you can read here:

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/13/revisiting-windows-azure-shared-access-signature/

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/